# How to have equal padding on both side of a div. CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, padding, centering

I have this element:

```
<div class="menubar">
    <a href="http://home.com"><img src="../img/home_button.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://home.com/a"><img src="../img/a_button.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://home.com/b"><img src="../img/b_button.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://home.com/c"><img src="../img/c_button.png"/></a>
</div>
```

My goal is to have the content of the menubar div being centered.

Using `display: table;` and `margin:auto;` achieves that but the background image I am using is cropped to fit only the div's content:

```
.menubar {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:url(/img/menubar_background.png);
}
```

So then, I have this other version that adds 50% padding to both sides, but the problem is that the total width of the result is 100% + the width of the buttons.

```
.menubar {
    padding-right:50%;
    padding-left:50%;
    background-image:url(/img/menubar_background.png);
}
```

I achieve something closer by using `max-width:960px` (100%) but there's still a problem: It doesn't actually apply the same amount of padding to both side. It ends up padding 50% to the left and whatever is left to reach 960px to the right.

Any help welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use text-align instead.

```
.menubar {
  text-align:center;
  background-image:url(/img/menubar_background.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the element's width you can use `calc`:

```css
.menubar {
  --menu-width: 112px;
  width: var(--menu-width);
  padding-left: calc((100% - var(--menu-width)) / 2);
  padding-right: calc((100% - var(--menu-width)) / 2);
  color: #4fff09;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
    menu bar content
</div>
```